# How can I make a radial checkerboard?

Tags: shaders

How can I make a radial checkerboard pattern like this in the shader editor?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One method is to use two checker textures, one driven by a radial gradient, and the other driven by a spherical gradient, then combine the two together using a mixrgb node set to difference.  Here are the results and the node setup.

[image: The result]

[image: The node setup]

If you want something besides black and white, you can pass the output from the difference node into a color ramp with two colors.

[image: Using a colorramp node to change the colors]

If you want more than 2 colors, you can change the two checker texture nodes to be 4 different colors, then use a 4 node color ramp to adjust as needed.

[image: creating a 4 color checker texture]

Comment: Very nice :). You can actually use the Black&white output as a mask for any other color combination.

Comment: Agreed.. but I'm still trying to get my head round the logic :)

Comment: I'm seeing four colors - is this just an optical illusion thing?

Comment: @Arsenal Looks like there's indeed a fourth light blue shade: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaB3n.png

Comment: +Jachym Michal Thanks for the idea, I found that using a color ramp worked and updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

A method to get polar coordinates in general is to use the (0-1) output of a *Gradient > Radial* texture as X, and the *Length* of the XY coordinate as Y:

[image]

The blue nodes above are just to ensure X is always an even integer, and give the user a basic interface, should you want to group the cluster.